If nothing changes when the non-provisional is filed, do you just submit a copy of the provisional?
Scenario One:
The non-provisional is identical to the provisional.
In this scenario, does the inventor simply submit a copy of the provisional when filing for the non-provisional? Or do they claim the provisional without submitting additional documents?

Scenario Two:
The non-provisional contains either new or modified content from the provisional.
In this scenario, what document is actually submitted in the non-provisional?
